# Where can I find large French texts in .txt format ?

Tags: ressources, littérature

I need to download a long roman/novel in .txt format as a reference so that I can analyze it for some kinda of concordance and finding phrases that I can use as examples.

By this way I can improve my skill in French grammar and discover the *true application* of words in sentences…

Comment: http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/author/44 for example. This website is full of Classic books for free, simply pick an author.

Comment: 1) These resources exist more in *epub* and *pdf* formats than in *txt* format. 2) IMHO this is more a question of how to use Google than an actual question about the french language.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt: You can download all books on [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/FR_Principal) in ePub, ePub Kindle, HTML and  **.txt**.

Comment: @Laure ah, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious answer is [the Gutenberg project](http://www.gutenberg.org/), with [thousands books in french](http://www.gutenberg.org/browse/languages/fr).

If you want to analyze french texts other than novels, an option is to extract text from [french news](https://news.google.fr/nwshp?hl=fr) with the [Readability](https://www.readability.com/) service.